# Reading sql table with a single general dynamic function

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to create a function that reads more easy any sql table no matter what number of columns.

```
class control_panel {
    public function read_table($table_name, array $col_names) {
        global $db;
        $i = 0;
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table_name");
        while($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $i++;
            foreach($col_names as $col_name) {
                $cols[] = $data->$col_name;
            }
        }
        var_dump($cols);
        $nr_cols = count($cols);
        /*for($j = 0; $j <= $nr_cols  $j++) {
            $cols[$j] = 
        }*/
    }
}
$cp = new control_panel;
$col_names = array('ID', 'NewsTitle', 'NewsDescrption');
$cp->read_table('newss', $col_names);
```

Table structure:

```
ID  NewsTitle  NewsDescrption
1   title      description
10  sda        sd
```

Current output of the var_dump is:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => string 'title' (length=5)
  2 => string 'descroierererer' (length=15)
  3 => string '10' (length=2)
  4 => string 'sda' (length=3)
  5 => string 'sd' (length=2)
```

Expected output is to echo the table rows when I do `$cp->read_table('newss', $col_names);` in this way:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>title</td>
  <td>description</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>sda</td>
  <td>sd</td>
</tr>
```

UPDATE change firts block of code to this as per David Jones answer.

```
public function read_table($table_name, array $col_names) {
    global $db;
    $results = array();
    $result = $db->query("SELECT ".implode(',', $col_names)." FROM $table_name");
    while($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $results[] = $data;
    }
    foreach($results as $result) {
        // how do I ouput dinamically here
        //echo $result->$col_name...... this would lied to another array
    }
}
```

Comment: share code for read_table function?

Comment: @NaincyGupta It is in the code. First block.

Comment: I will need a final answer to output exactly like I want to.

Comment: You only have tables that you don't need to join? Sounds like bad DB design. And this: "I will need a final answer to output exactly like I want to." Stackoverflow should lead you in the right direction, so that you understand things. Not that you can copy&paste code. It's not code writing service.

Comment: @fancyPants From what I know JOINS are bad for performance. That is true "Stackoverflow should lead you in the right direction", but I am kind of struggling for some time, and ran out of ideas.

Comment: Well, then throw everything you know about joins over board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You should only select the columns that you pass in rather than the whole table to limit un needed processing.

```
class control_panel {
    public function read_table($table_name, array $col_names) {
        global $db;

        $results = array();

        $result = $db->query("SELECT ".implode(',', $col_names)." FROM $table_name");
        while($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
            $results[] = $data;
        }

        return $results;
    }
}

$cp = new control_panel;
$col_names = array('ID', 'NewsTitle', 'NewsDescrption');
$results = $cp->read_table('newss', $col_names);

$table = '';
foreach ($results as $item) {
    $table .= '<tr>
                   <td>'.$item->ID.'</td>
                   <td>'.$item->NewsTitle.'</td>
                  <td>'.$item->NesDescription.'</td>
              </tr>';
}

var_dump($table);
```

This should return an array of objects. Then you can access each column in a loop to show your table.

UPDATE:

You shouldn't loop through and generate your table inside the method as it is suppose to be generic and reusable. Instead return the results and loop in the controller or main PHP file.

Comment: I was thinking directory, would it be possible, without getting an array of objects.

Comment: Do you need an array of arrays instead??

Comment: Actually it's ok with objects, trying to see how to loop to get that output.

Comment: If you get stuck update your answer and i'll have a look at it

Comment: Updated. Let me know.

Comment: Ok, will do like this.